# Move 10 files related to one particulare CustomerNo to a directory and Needs to be automated

Tags: dos

I have 10 different xml files that are related to a CustomerNO

CustUSA_10201_20130912.xml,

CustCAN_10201__20130912.xml,

CustENG_10201_20130912.xml

etc.....

Cust USA_10202_20130911.xml,

Cust CAN_10202_20130911.xml,

Cust ENG_10202_20130911.xml,

etc...

How can I automate this so that all the 10 files related to each CustomerNO can be moved at once so when I process them I have all the 10 at a time.

Would really appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  And I suspect this isn't actually a [dos] question; you should tag your question with what you're trying to use (e.g., [batch], [perl], etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This will work in Windows (not DOS but the long file names hints that you might not be in DOS)

move Cust*20130912.xml destination

And change 20130912 accordingly.